# Mongo update removing other keys in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying mongo update where one document key from a different collection is inserted into another collection.

## CODE

```
// update user document with remove of otp and new state set.
    updateOne = await db.collection(_collection).updateOne(
      // search basis.
      __docUpdateSearchBasis,
      // updates.
      __docUpdateBasis
    )
```

## RESULT

[image]

Comment: have you tried with `{$set : __docUpdateBasis}`? can you post complete query?

Comment: yes that too doing same

Comment: can you post complete query with definition and some documents before and after update?

Comment: that's too long.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make query like this:

```
updateOne = await db.collection(_collection).findOneAndUpdate(
//Condition
{
    _id: req.user.id
},
//Update what you want
{
    $set: {
        key: value
    }
});
```